# Display Tableau label to show group breakdown

Tags: tableau-api

I grouped my countries as followed (I used create --> group):
Asia = HK, JP, SG & Other = all other countries

So I am working with the following dimensions:
"Region" is the group created above. "Country" is the list of countries (e.g. HK, JP, SG, VT, CA, US, etc). "Date" & "Quantity"

I displayed a line chart that show trend for these 2 groups, so basically, on the same graph, one line shows the trend for "Other" and the other shows the trend for "Asia". "Day" is on the column shelf and quantity is on the row shelf, and I put Region on the color shelf to obtain the 2 lines. I also bring "Country" on the Filter shelf since I want to be able to view individual countries.

In the labels, when "ALL" is selected for "Country", I am able to display "Other" and "Asia". What I want is the label to change to the actual country when I select an individual country. For instance, if I select HK, I will only see the HK line, which is fine, but the problem is that it is labelled as "Asia" instead of HK. How can I make this happen?

I tried to add "Country" to the Label mark, unfortunately, that breaks down the trend lines to show "Other" and then all the countries that fall under Asia. I really just want to have 2 lines (or just one it a single country from "Country" is selected).

I have been banging my head trying calculated fields and parameters and can't get this to work. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bit extreme, but I can't think of another way.

With your 'Region' group on color and label, Tableau has no way of knowing when it is appropriate to change label to 'Country.' A calculated field would be very difficult to create here.

What I would propose is two completely separate sheets that are switched upon a user's input. [Here is some documentation on how to create a sheet selector.](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dashboards_sheet_selector.htm)

The method would generally be to:

1. Create a string **parameter**. Inside the parameter creation window there is an option "Add from Field" which would allow you to import all of your "Country" names. You will need to add an "All" label on this screen as well.
2. Create two views. One which is the one you already have that will show "All" and have two lines. The other **new sheet** will be designed for only when a single selection from the parameter list is made. It will only show one line that is labeled with the parameter (Country) name. You can design it however you'd like since its a totally separate sheet.
3. Follow the instructions in the link given above. In the article, on the step labeled "Type the current view's name (like “Map”) in the text box, and click the Add Item button." you will want to type the parameter name "All" in your first sheet and then in the second sheet you will want to individually label each country. The parameter drop down will trigger one sheet or the other for display.

A major consideration here is how often any fields are added to [Country]. Keep in mind that the parameter list will not automatically be adjusted if the underlying data changes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, Daniel. It worked!

Comment: Great to hear!!